# Post an xml File to nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, express

i am having an xml file.I need to expose an api in such a way that it can consume xml files through nodejs server api.

how can i receive a simple xml file in my nodejs server. i need a nodejs server script.

Comment: what you are expecting ??you want to display xml file as response through nodejs server???????

Comment: A client should access my api ,so that he can post xml file by accessing my api url and i just want to receive a xml file on my server.

Comment: In what way you want to post xml like through body or by reading a text file and converting into xml and displaying the xml file as response

Comment: i would like to post the xml data through body and read it in server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code after struggling sometime I successfully get the code as per your need.

```
var express = require('express');
var fs=require('fs');
var app = express();
var conf;
var result;
app.get('/Excel', function(req, res){
    result=fs.readFileSync('E:/User/nodejs/nodejs/tasks/result.xml');
    res.end(result);
});
app.post('/posting',function(req,res){  
var body = '';
req.on('data', function(data) {
        body += data;
    });

    req.on('end', function (){
        fs.writeFile('E:/User/nodejs/nodejs/tasks/result.xml', body, function() {
           console.log(body);
            res.end('Successfully Posted');
        });
    });

});
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

After you run the server `Post` the data in content-type as application/xml using `http://localhost:3000/posting` and place your code in body and as result `result.xml` file will be created with the data.And you can get this file by  `http://localhost:3000/Excel`.Hope this helps for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple XML parser middleware such as [express-xml-bodyparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-xml-bodyparser). A working examples with express can be found in the above mentioned site.